# Magento 2 - Different billing and shipping address

Tags: magento2, php

I would like to force the user to use the default billing address he has in its account on checkout.

So I set the quote billing address programatically and hide / uncheck the checkbox "My billing and shipping address are the same" but when the user is changing the shipping address it stills updating the billing address how can I fix this ?

Comment: You can do it using Magento event observer.